# How to access a bash environment variable from within R in emacs-ess

Tags: r, bash, emacs, environment-variables, ess

In my .bashrc, I have the line:

```
export SETTINGS=/home/user/settings.xml
```

If I load R in bash, I can access this variable using the `Sys.getenv` function:

```
Sys.getenv("SETTINGS")
"/home/user/settings.xml"
```

If I open up R in Emacs (M-x R), SETTINGS is empty:

```
Sys.getenv("SETTINGS")
""
```

What I have tried:

1. adding the following to .emacs, based on  [How do I make Emacs recognize bash environment variables for compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663396/how-do-i-make-emacs-recognize-bash-environment-variables-for-compilation)

   ```
   ;; get environment vars from .bashrc
   (let ((path (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bashrc; echo -n $SETTINGS")))
     (setenv "SETTINGS" path))
   ```
2. opening up bash in emacs using `M-x term`

   ```
   echo $SETTINGS         # works
   R
   Sys.getenv("SETTINGS") #works
   ```
3. If I open emacs from the terminal, the SETTINGS variable is available as expected.  Opening emacs from the Applications menu (with either the command `/usr/bin/emacs23 %F` or `emacs`) does not work.
4. comparing output from `session("env")` when loading R in bash vs emacs, but nothing stands out other than (bash = <, emacs = >):

   ```
   > INSIDE_EMACS=23.3.1,comint
   6d5
   < SETTINGS=/home/user/settings.xml
   9c8
   < SHLVL=1
   > SHLVL=0
   14a14
   > PAGER=cat
   16d15
   < PAGER=/usr/bin/pager
   19d17
   < COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
   25c23
   < WINDOWID=14680069
   > DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=1020ce948b944a88113395253627645060000001863000
   < TERM=xterm
   > TERM=dumb
   ```

Can I either

1. access SETTINGS from within R in emacs-ess
2. export SETTINGS somewhere that I can access it?

Comment: How are you starting Emacs?  If you start a bash shell (with SETTINGS in the environment), and start Emacs from there, it should work.  As it is, seems that the parent process does not have this environment variable (starting from Gnome shell or such?).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I updated my answer (see point #3). Opening from the terminal works. Opening with a calls to `/usr/bin/emacs23 %F` from the Applications menu, Gnome-do, or a keyboard shortcut does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about R and self-defined environment variables, but I set the PATH variable in emacs to the same value as in my bashrc. I modified my code to your problem, give it a shot and let me know if it works.

```
;; set env variable in Emacs
(getenv "SETTINGS")
(setenv "SETTINGS" "/home/user/settings.xml")
```

Original code (for PATH) is:

```
;; Emacs has its own path variable
(getenv "PATH")
 (setenv "PATH"
(concat
 "/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux" ":"
(getenv "PATH")))
```

Answer (score 3):

the .bashrc might not be read when the xsession is started. Try adding

```
export SETTINGS=/home/user/settings.xml
```

in the `.xsessionrc` or the `.gnomerc` (if you are using gnome). Those file are loaded at startup for the X session.

Comment: They are probably better than xsesssionrc because they are read on login by ssh.

Answer (score 0):

If you start you an R session inside emacs, then the R session will have the same environment variables as emacs. So you should first make sure that you start emacs in such a way that its environment contains your SETTINGS variable. That way, your R session, which you start inside emacs, will have SETTINGS also in its environment. How exactly to achieve this depends on your system.

Comment: My systems are Ubuntu and RedHat; do you have any further advice? How can I see the environment inside emacs? if I open up a bash terminal using `M-x term` in emacs, the variables are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
SETTINGS <- "/home/user/settings.xml"
```

in `.Rprofile` as a work-around.

Comment: That would be a suitable workaround except that I want to be able to access the variable in "R --vanilla" mode